# how can i add extra element style for external css file?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

This is my site header with 2 style sheets included:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

This code is in the jquery-ui.css file:

```
.ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    background: #dadada url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #212121;
}
```

I also use an external style sheet from jquery.com:
//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Now I need change the opacity property for ui-state-hover, without downloading the css file and editing it manually, to:

```
.ui-state-hover{
opacity:0.1;
}
```

So in my internal style.css file I added:

```
.ui-state-hover{
    opacity:0.1;
    }
```

But, it does not work...

How can I add extra style rules without downloading, editing the file manually and uploading? Should I just use internal style sheet?

Comment: It doesn't work because the definition in the library is more *specific*. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: .ui-state-hover {opacity: 0.1 !important;}

Comment: My suggestion is, you download all those CSS & JS files Coz future can't be predicted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because the definition in the library is more specific http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

thanks to techfoobar

Answer (score 2):

use

```
.ui-state-hover{
    opacity:0.1 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `!important` in your internal stylesheet.

Please check the following code..

```
.ui-state-hover{
    opacity:0.1 !important;
    }
```

hope this will help you..

Or switch the order of the load of stylesheet like following ..

```
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Answer (score 0):

switch the download order for your CSS:

```
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Load first the UI, then your own CSS, this will allow you to override some settings without the use of (bad) !important.

Be sure to copy the exact specific selector to your own CSS, then override will happen.